# How can we prove that f(a)*g(a)=(f*g)(a) for any two polynomials f,g?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have an idea how to prove it, but I'm not sure if it's right. So a verification would be nice, and if it's wrong, a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

This is my solution:

Let $deg(f)=k; deg(g)=m;$ and let $n$ be the degree of $f*g$.

Then $$(f*g)(a)= \sum_n C_n*a^n $$ where $$C_n = \sum_i f_i * k_{n-i}$$

Now we take $f(a)*g(a)$

$$ f(a)*g(a) = (f_k*a^k+f_{k-1}*a^{k-1}+...+f_0)*(g_m*a^m+g_{m-1}*a^{m-1}+...+g_0) $$

If we expand this, we'll see:

$$ f(a)*g(a) = (f_0 * g_0)*a^0 + (f_0 * g_1 + f_1 * g_0)*a^1 + ... + (f_0 * g_{k+m} + ... + f_{k+m} * g_0)*a^{k+m} $$

We can shorten this expression by displaying each coefficient as a sum, $C$ such that

$$C_{k+m} = \sum_i f_i * k_{k+m-i}$$

Finally, we can conclude that

$$f(a)*g(a) = \sum_{k+m} C_{k+m}*a^{k+m} $$

Now what's left to prove is that $n=m+k$ which is already a defined property of polynomials:

$$deg(f*g)=deg(f)+deg(g)=m+k$$

Comment: I am confused by your query.  What exactly is the definition that you were given for $(f * g)(x)$?  Here, I am assuming that you are using $(f * g)$ to signify $(f \times g)$.  The way that I was taught, the definition of $(f \times g)(x)$ is $f(x) \times g(x)$.  If you accept that definition, and if I have correctly interpreted your use of "*", then, according to the definition, **there is nothing to prove**.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the * symbol to signify ×, but I'm trying to prove this definition. Perhaps you weren't taught the proof to this definition?

Comment: Fair enough.  However, if you are trying to *prove the definition*, then you must be using **some other definition** for $(f \times g)(x).$  What **precisely** is the definition that you wish to start with?

Comment: "*Perhaps you weren't taught the proof to this* **definition**"  Definitions aren't proven... they are merely definitions.  Without the definition, $f\cdot g$ makes no sense... the sequence of symbols literally not being defined yet.  Suppose I have a dog and I named my dog "Fido."  Your request to prove $(f\cdot g)(a)=f(a)\cdot g(a)$ is like asking for a mathematical proof of the fact that my dog's name must be Fido.  There is no proof... it just is, and it is because we defined it that way.  The only reason why the dog's name is Fido is because I said it is... no other reason.

Comment: @JMoravitz Unclear.  I suspect that the OP has a different idea in mind, namely that to evaluate (for example) $(f\times g)(a)$ what you **have to do** is first create the polynomial $h(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$, and then evaluate $h(a)$.  I was waiting for the OP to say that, so that I could then ask him to take a step back and consider the significance of $h(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$ **for any value of** $x$, in the first place.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh I'm sorry, it's perhaps a language barrier. $(f×g)(a)$ is defined as the polynomial expression in field $F$ where $x=a$. The operation × itself is defined as the multiplication of two polynomials, which itself is defined using the first two sigma expressions in my question.

Comment: @user2661923 Precisely. Imagine the $a$ equals some matrix such as $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$, and the polynomials f,g are $x^2+x$ and $x-1$ respectively. It'd be easier to plug the matrix a into $x^3 - x$ than evaluating the two polynomials and then multiplying them.

Comment: Then, take a look at my previous comment.  Specifying $h(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$, in an of itself, as an algorithmic step in the definition of $(f\times g)(x)$ indicates **immediately**, without any further analysis needed, based on the basic definition of a polynomial, that for **any value** $(x)$, including $(x=a)$, you have that $h(x) = f(x) \times g(x).$  Therefore, by the definition of $(f\times g)(x)$, **which you have chosen**, you know **immediately** that $(f\times g)(a) = f(a) \times g(a).$  ...see next comment

Comment: You therefore know this, without any need to construct the generic polynomial $h(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$ and then evaluate $h(a).$

Comment: @user2661923 I'm not sure what "indicates immediately" means. $(f×g)$ is the product of two polynomials. It's a third, unknown polynomial. In other words, it's a series of some number of coefficients. Once evaluated to $a$, it becomes a new function. Whereas $f(a)×g(a)$ is just the product of two functions in whatever field $a$ is in.

Comment: @AlexOsheter No, you are misinterpreting the meaning of a polynomial.  Once you know that $h(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$, for **any** value of $x$, which is what it means for one polynomial to represent the product of two other polynomials, then you know that the formula $h(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$ holds for the specific value $(x=a)$.  Therefore, you *immediately* know that $h(a) = f(a) \times g(a).$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120340/discussion-between-alex-osheter-and-user2661923).

Comment: @user2661923 After seeing all your work in the chat I wanted to say, that -as I understand it- the question intended to ask by OP is, if the evaluation map is an algebra-homomorphism from the space of algebraic polynomials to the real numbers. To be more precise: the space of algebraic polynomials (to order n) is the free group generated over $\mathbb{R}$ with the given basis $(1,x,\ldots,x^n)$ and the evaluation map $E_a$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$ takes that polynomial and evaluates it at $a$. The question then reads as $E_a(f)\times E_a(g)=E_a(f\times g)$.

Comment: @dennis_s Okay, interesting comment - and here, I am clearly out of my depth.  My understanding of $[E_1]:~h(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$ is **limited** to : equation $E_1$ automatically holds for any value of $x$.  If I understand your comment correctly, you are interpreting equation $E_1$ differently, which puts me out of my depth.

Comment: @user2661923 The way the question was asked seemed to see polynomials as functions, with domains and codomains as you wrote, where cleary the product of two functions is defined pointwise by the prodoct of their values at that point. In the sense of algebraic polynomials a polynomial is an 'abstract' object $f=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$ with no further meaning. $f+g$ is defined by addition of coefficients and $f*g$ is defined by the formula well known from polynomials as functions. Now you can also evaluate this polynomial at any certain point of any certain algebra (here $\mathbb{R}$, I guess).

Comment: @dennis_s If you have a way of interpreting and then answering the OP's query in a way that will completely satisfy the OP, then I encourage you to post an answer.  My only caveats are [1] Since I didn't understand your previous comment [**as is**], the OP might not either - so you would have to make your answer very simple and clear and detailed [2] If the OP is having trouble articulating the question that he really wants to ask, and you think that you know what it is, you probably want to start your answer with a clear heavily detailed explanation of what you think the OP is really asking.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm still curious if I could solve your first caveat, since part of answering the question was due to your chat with OP.

Comment: @dennis_s Having never studied Field Theory, I never the less do have a somewhat vague
intuition around the distinctions that you are drawing.  You are distinguishing
between the interpretation of polynomials that I am accustomed to, a polynomial
map, and the alternative interpetation, an abstraction of the object 
behind the map: introduce an abstract variable t and its powers 
$t^k, k\in \mathbb{N}$, which have no other meaning than being different from 
each other.  ...see next comment.

Comment: @dennis_s I understand where you are going with this, and consider the whole topic one
that I would have to study Field Theory for quite some time on, in order to 
be able to evaluate whether a given *proof* was valid.  I question what the 
source of the OP's problem is, and what the OP's math background is.  I also
question if the OP is clear on the distinction between a polynomial map and an
abstraction of the object behind the map.   ...see next comment

Comment: @dennis_s I also question whether the OP will
be able to rigorously evaluate your (necessary) use of a homomorphism - as I say,
I am not currently qualified to do so.
However, given the query broached by the OP, I see no alternative than the 
analysis/approach that you are taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of this answer is to clarify some confusion which arose in the comment section. To begin with, you presented everything one needs to consider to show what I assume you intended to ask.

The important part here might be to understand the difference between polynomials as maps and polynomials as somewhat algebraic objects. For simplicity I will only refer to $\mathbb{R}$, but feel free to always replace that with any algebra you have in mind.

A polynomial map of degree $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that takes a value $x$ and associates a value $f(x):=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$, where $x^k$ is the $k$-th power of $x$ and $a_k\in\mathbb{R}$, $a_n\neq 0$. Since we now how to multiply functions with values in $\mathbb{R}$, that is the value of $f\times g$ at at point $x$ is defined to be $(f\times g)(x):=f(x)\times g(x)$, we can show that for two polynomial maps $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $g(x):= \sum_{k=0}^mb_kx^k$ the product again is a polynomial map given by $h(x):=(f\times g)(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}c_kx^k$, where $c_k:=\sum_{l=0}^ka_lb_{k-l}$ .

Since this product formula for polynomials seems to be true in the usual algebras that come to mind quickly, one might want to abstract the object behind the map. This can be done algebraically by introducing an abstract variable $t$ and its powers $t^k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, which have no other meaning than being different from each other. Having these we can introduce the set
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}[t]:=\{\sum_{k=0}^na_kt^k:\ a_k\in\mathbb{R}, n\in\mathbb{N}\}
\end{align*}
which can be equipped with a scalar multiplication $\lambda\times f:=\sum_{k=0}^n(\lambda a_k)t^k$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and an addition $f+g:=\sum_{k=0}^n(a_k+b_k)t^k$ with $f:=\sum_{k=0}^na_kt^k$ and $g:=\sum_{k=0}^nb_kt^k$ elements in $\mathbb{R}[t]$. Hence this set is a real vector space with basis $(1,t,t^2,\ldots)$. On top of that we can equip $\mathbb{R}[t]$ with a multiplication, making it an algebra, by $f\times g:=\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}c_kt^k$, where $c_k:=\sum_{l=0}^ka_lb_{k-l}$. This definition is designed to match the multiplication of polynomial maps!

Having developed this notion of algebraic polynomials the link between these and polynomial maps is given by the so called evaluation maps. For each $a\in\mathbb{R}$ there is a map $E_a:\mathbb{R}[t]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, taking a polynomial $f$ and assigning to it the real number $\sum_{k=0}^na_ka^k$, or to be more precise it sends the coefficient $a_k$ of the base element $t^k$ to $a_k\times a^k$ and sums over all these real numbers afterwards. Then OP's question might read as 'How to prove that $E_a$ is an algebra homomorphism, especially that $E_a$ is multiplicative, i.e.
\begin{align}
E_a(f)\times_\mathbb{R} E_a(g)=E_a(f\times_{\mathbb{R}[t]} g).
\end{align}
Since one doesn't naturally care between the difference of algebraic polynomials and polynomial maps, one often writes $f(a)=E_a(f)$, meaning both at once or whatever is needed in that moment (regarding $f$!).

Returning to your question: Your calculation and expansion revalidates the knowledge of the coefficients of the product of two polynomial maps, which is needed here! To the abstract polynomial $f$ we consider the polynomial map $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (or just $f$ if we don't care) with the exact same coefficients. Then we have that $E_a(f)=\tilde{f}(a)$ and hence $E_a(f)\times E_a(g)=\tilde{f}(a)\times\tilde{g}(a)=(\tilde{f}\times \tilde{g})(a)$, where the last equation is the definition of multiplication of maps! Now we have $(\tilde{f}\times \tilde{g})(a)=E_a(f\times g)$ by the definition of multiplication in $\mathbb{R}[t]$ which was designed to fit in that way.

I hope that clarifies a bit of the questions that occured.

Comment: Stellar explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @alexosheter Thanks! Glad I could help.